How would I build a weighting algorithm for a marketplace of sellers?
I have a marketplace that is similar to how Fiverr works. Service providers say that a given "gig" or service will take a given number of days. I want to start giving sorting/visibility preference to the service providers that deliver on time or before for more weight. Those that fail to deliver in time will be penalized.
What are some ways that I can assign and track a weighted rating based on delivery performance over time? Would the following pseudo code be on the right track?
// Everyone has a starting weight of 1
on-time delivery = current weight * 1.1
early delivery = current weight * 1.2
late delivery = current weight * .9
fail to deliver = current weight * .75

Sort sellers by weight descending

I'm not sure these if these values make sense or would weight too quickly. Any help is appreciated!

I would only use a limited time span (or only the last n calls) to calculate the value not all events since system-start.

You could show percentile bands for both time & budget, in both cases based on reality/prediction.

Rather than a limited time span I'd use a time weighted average of the providers rating for each job. As for the weights (time and performance), you probably need to run some back-testing to see how well they predict performance on the next job.

Your approach is alright, but I would recommend trying exponential moving average.
Firstly, it takes into account previous samples (sample in this case would be the quality of delivery) with weight of alpha and the new sample with 1 - alpha. This means, previous samples have bigger impact than the just taken sample, which could be more fair to people who for example delivered always on time but suddenly have few bad deliveries. Their overall weight wouldn't drop that much as for someone who had less on time deliveries and suddenly has bad ones. This brings some kind of reputation element.
Second advantage is that the weights fluctuate less. There is a smaller variance. In your approach people with a lot of bad deliveries will have weights close to zero pretty quicky, and this could potentially lead to some numeric problems. And also people with a lot of good deliveries could have their weights too big, causing potential overflows.
I would recommend to choose alpha as 0.9 to 0.99. This value is usually used, for example in some neural network optimizers, like Adam, but of course you should try different values and see how the weights change. You can use the weight change factors as you proposed, it's fine.
Example update with alpha = 0.99:
weight = weight * 0.99 + 0.01 * 1.2 // early delivery

The smaller the alpha, the lesser the fluctuations and the more predominant is the history of samples over one sample.

I think this is exactly what I was looking for. I'm not super great at reading formulas, but it's basically weight = weight * alpha + (1 - alpha) * weight change factor?

Kind of a followup question, does it make sense to store these as integers? Like take the resulting weight and multiply by 1000? Then when calculating, divide by the current weight by 1000?

I think I can just put my starting weight to be 1000 and do some rounding. Thanks again!

Yeah, you could do that, but I think it might be an unnecessary complication and it also rounds the accuracy to fixed decimal place. Using double or even float, if you desire to save space, should be completely fine. and you will have much more granularity than ever using fixed point numbers. Do you have any concrete motivation why would you like to store it as integer? I don't really see any.

I think that databases sort based on integer faster than double/float columns. Probably not necessary given my data size.
